# Data does not exist for row/column when selectindexchange on Dropdownlist when clicked on dropdownlist.item.insert as empty position on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, webforms

When I'm choosing additional (empty) position on Dropdownlist created by DropDownList.Item.Insert whole application is terminated.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    DropDownList4.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
                    DropDownList4.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                    String strConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\projects.accdb";
                    String strQuery = "select * from projects";
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnString); ;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    try
                    {
                        
                        con.Open();
                        DropDownList4.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        DropDownList4.DataTextField = "Project_name";
                        DropDownList4.DataValueField = "ID";
                        DropDownList4.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }

protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\projects.accdb";
            string strQuery = "select * from projects where" + " ID = @ID";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataReader myreader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    myreader.Read();
                    TextBox12.Text = myreader["Project_name"].ToString();
                    TextBox2.Text = myreader["Owner"].ToString();
                    
                    myreader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

As I'm thinking the reason is that the empty value does not exist in DB (but it is just created every time on Page_load by DropDownList4.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""))). How to exclude from checking in DB first empty position on DropDownList?

Edited:

```
   ...
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    { 
    con.Open();
    DropDownList4.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value == null || DropDownList4.SelectedItem == null)
    {
    }
    DropDownList4.DataTextField = "Project_name";
    DropDownList4.DataValueField = "ID";
    DropDownList4.DataBind();
    }
```

Still does not working

Edited:

```
string selected = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selected))
            {
                
            }
```

Now - It's working :)

Comment: You could perhaps try debugging the problem?

Comment: Maybe a check if DropDownList4.SelectedItem is null or DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value is null or anyway whatever the empty value is, and return if that's the case.

Comment: "System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message=No data exist for row/column"

Comment: What is the empty list item for? 
Yes, before you read from the database in your second block you should check that the user hasn't selected the empty item. In this case update the textboxes to blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need (and want to) add the blank dropdown row AFTER you fill the dropdown.

So, say we have this markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            Height="26px" Width="207px" AutoPostBack="True" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And I DO suggest that you put the DataValue/Text settings in the control - really no need or advantage to putting that code in code behind.

And we don't need (or want) to re-load or re-insert the extra blank dropdown choice each time - so load the dropdown ONLY one time (the PostBack = false in page load as you attempted is correct).

So, we will select a hotel, and then pull that ONE database row for additional information - shove into a few text boxes as your code example does.

I suggest this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

            OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select.. -", "0"));
        }
    }

    DataTable MyRstP(OleDbCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HotelPK = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value as string;
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels where ID = @ID";
        OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = HotelPK;

        DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        if (rstData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rstData.Rows[0];
            TextBox1.Text = OneRow["HotelName"].ToString();
            txtTaxRate.Text = OneRow["HotelTax"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

We also assume and have AutoPostBack = true for the drop list to fire each time we change it.